# How can the particle in plane progressive harmonic wave have minimum potential energy at one of the extreme position?

Tags: waves, harmonic-oscillator, plane-wave

[consider this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkySB.jpg)
context: These are fill in the blanks sort of questions, the above image contains solution.

### My reasoning

**A** and **B** should be in SHM and we know that in SHM *Kinetic Energy*  is max at mean position and we assumed that Potential energy is zero at mean position. And at extreme PE is max. **A** should have more KE and it should have PE min. **B** has more PE  and less KE.

 
turns out my reasoning is wrong

### Teacher's reasoning

$<\frac{KE}{Volume}> = \frac{1}{4}\rho A^2\omega^2$

$<\frac{PE}{Volume}> = \frac{1}{4}\rho A^2\omega^2$

KE and PE are equal.

since **A** has more KE, it should also have more PE(due to above two formulas), so point A not only possess more KE but also more PE.

since Point B has less KE, it should also have less PE(from above formulas)

**Opinion**

Formula wise what my teacher is saying correct but if we look at this question in concept wise, my answer should be correct as at the end of the day these particles are performing SHM. My teacher's explanation is not satisfactory, I want to know which one should be correct. Or am I looking at this problem in the wrong way the whole time?, if I'm wrong why?

---

### **Derivation for $<\frac{KE}{Volume}> = \frac{1}{4}\rho A^2\omega^2$(KE per unit volume average value)** 
[Look at this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEung.jpg)
Let eqn of wave $$y = A\sin(\omega t - kx)$$
$$dm = dx \mu$$
where $\mu$ is linear mass density,
Let velocity of particle along vertical axis be: $V_{p}$
$$V_{p} = \frac{dy}{dt} = A\omega \cos(\omega t - kx)$$
$$KE = \frac{1}{2}dm {V_{p}}^2$$
Volume of particle : $s (dx)$ where $s$ is cross section area of rope/string.
Then density of particle will be:
$\frac{\mu}{s} = \rho$
$$<\frac{KE}{Volume}> = <\frac{\frac{1}{2}m{V_p}^2}{V}>$$
$$<\frac{KE}{volume}> = <\frac{1}{2}\rho A^2 \omega^2 \cos^2(\omega t - kx)>$$
$<cos^2(\theta)> = \frac{1}{2}$
$$<\frac{KE}{Volume}> = \frac{1}{4}\rho A^2\omega^2$$

[original solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X28k0.jpg)

**Derivation for $<\frac{PE}{Volume}> = \frac{1}{4}\rho A^2\omega^2$(PE per unit volume average value)** 
[Look at this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUkSE.jpg)

original length of particle: $dx$
new length of particle due to tension: $\sqrt{dx^2 + dy^2}$
formulas that are handy: $(1+x)^n = 1+ nx$
change in length of particle: $\sqrt{dx^2 + dy^2}- dx$
$$=> dx[1+(\frac{dy}{dx})^2]^\frac{1}{2} - dx => dx[1+\frac{1}{2}(\frac{dy}{dx})^2]-dx$$
$$=> \frac{1}{2}(\frac{dy}{dx})^2 dx$$
change in length : $\frac{1}{2}(\frac{dy}{dx})^2 dx$

**Work done by tension in extension = change in PE energy**

Assume that PE intially is zero
$$T.\frac{1}{2}(\frac{dy}{dx})^2 dx = du_{f} - du_{i} = du$$
$\frac{du}{dx} = \frac{1}{2}\mu A^2 \omega^2 cos^2(\omega t - kx)$

*You can derive $\frac{du}{dx}$ from $T.\frac{1}{2}(\frac{dy}{dx})^2 dx = du$* by putting $T = \mu v^2$

 Volume of particle = s(dx)
$$<\frac{PE}{volume}> = <\frac{du}{s dx}>$$
$$<\frac{PE}{volume}> = <\frac{\frac{1}{2}\mu A^2 \omega^2 cos^2(\omega t - kx)dx}{s(dx)}>$$
$$<\frac{PE}{volume}> = <\frac{\mu}{s}A^2\omega^2\frac{1}{2}cos^2(\omega t - kx)>$$

$$<\frac{PE}{volume}> = \frac{1}{4}\rho A^2 \omega^2$$

Comment: What is the question then?

Comment: @sslucifer [this is the correct solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkySB.jpg) the quiz is like fill in the blanks type of thing, my reasoning is, Point A shouldn't have max PE but if you look at solution key it says Point A has max PE, question is How can point A have max potential energy when it is at equilibrium position? Am I wrong? or the quiz is wrong? Our teacher said something like it has to with slope of line something like that which didn't make sense to me thats why im asking here

Comment: I also forgot to mention they said $<\frac{KE}{Volume}> = \frac{1}{4}\rho A^2\omega^2 $ 

$<\frac{PE}{Volume}>= \frac{1}{4}\rho A^2\omega^2$ since KE and PE are equal(From above formula) as point A has more KE it should also have max PE, this was their main reasoning, but I'm confused, what they're is right formula wise, but wrong concept wise

Comment: There is still a lot of context that is missing. You should write the teacher’s question and solution in full so that someone can identify your problem. For example, what does $\rho$ represent?

Comment: How are A and B in SHM? It seems to me that A and B are in a potential well and if their energy is greater than potential well depth, then it will overcome the potential well and if it doesnt, it will perform oscillatory motion.(Note that it is not necessarily SHM). SHM is possible only for small displacement about the equilibrium position

Comment: @josephh $\rho$ represents density of rope/string, I hope we are on the same page

Comment: @Rambalheartremo Yes of course it does. But you cannot assume that everyone who reads your question knows what each quantity represents.